# how to listen to 192.168 with node?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to listen to an 192.168 port to access my node app from other devices and computers. What I'm doing wrong here? I'm on Mac (OSX Lion)

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, "192.168.1.122");
console.log('Server running at http://192.168.1.122/');
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Does it fail to connect? Does it work if you do only `.listen(1337)`?

Comment: How can I reach my node app that is running through other computers? This is my question basically

Answer (score 1):

Just leave off the address, it's unnecessary.  Then connect to it from another computer by accessing http://192.168.1.122:1337 in a browser, assuming that is ip address of the server within the local network.

If you want to access it from elsewhere (computers outside your local network), you need to find out your ip address to the outside world (whatismyip.com is handy for that), and then make sure your router has port 1337 pointed at the 122 machine.  Then access it by that ip address (and port 1337)

Comment: doesn't work for me! I listen to 1337 like this .listen(1337) and it's not accessible from my own computer

Comment: try and access `127.0.0.1:1337` on the computer it runs on

Answer (score 1):

Here are some helpful error messages:

- `EADDRNOTAVAIL` if you do not have that IP address associated with that machine.
- `EACCES` if you try to open a port you do not have access to (port <1024 as a user).
- `EADDRINUSE` if you try to open a port already opened.

If none of these are your problem, and node does not crash upon instantiating the port, you have a firewall or routing issue and diagnosing should begin there as it is most likely not a node.js issue.

Running this command on a clean box:

```
[jnovack@imac ~]$ node
> var http = require('http');
undefined
> http.createServer(function (req, res) {
...   res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
...   res.end('Hello World\n');
... }).listen(1337);
{ domain: null,
  _events:
   { request: [Function],
     connection: [Function: connectionListener] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  _connections: 0,
  connections: [Getter/Setter],
  allowHalfOpen: true,
  _handle:
   { writeQueueSize: 0,
     onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
     owner: [Circular] },
  httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
  _connectionKey: '4:0.0.0.0:1337' }
>
```

The object that returned shows that a successful http.listen has been completed.